From top to bottom
What do I call some specific letters?
   J I E D O B
   O D R E N L
   Y O R V E E
   F L O E E W
   U I U R N E
   L Z N Y A B
  
      _ _  
    \
     /
    \ 
     /
    \ 
     /
    _  _  
      /
     \
      /
     \ 
      /
     \ 
      _ _   
    \
     /
    \
     /
    \
     /
  _ _    
      /
     \
      /
     \
      /
     \
      _  _ 
       \
        /
       \
        /
       \
        /
       _ _  
     \
      /
     \
      /
     \
      /
     _


Some specific letters are called ...

 ... FALLEN.

 Reading the 6×6 grid columnwise, there are six words:

   joyful idolizer round everyone enable web

 In the diagram, each level has a three letter word, that from some reason is represented by two underscores. There's also a zig-zag line from one of the letters to the same letter in the word on the next level.

 These letters spell FALLEN, because they fall down to the next answer as shown in this simplified diagram, where the long squiggly lines are replaced with short arrows:


       F U N   joyful
       ↓
       F A N   idolizer
         ↓
       L A P   round
       ↓
     A L L   everyone
         ↓
         L E T   enable
           ↓
         N E T   web
         ↓
         •



That's it, nice job!
